# What would be a modern PHP tool to administer MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm looking for a modern tool to administer my Mongo database via web interface (like phpMyAdmin). I want it in PHP (so no MongoUI) and using MongoDB extension not the already deprecated Mongo extension (so no RockMongo, phpMoAdmin or phpMongodbAdmin). Are there any?